# How to log spring 6 webclient request body

Tags: spring, logging, webclient

I'm using spring boot 3 HTTP interface.

The request is a multipart/form-data request.
I want to log all the body parts with content-type and content.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://...")
        .defaultHeaders(header -> header.setBasicAuth("...", "..."))
        .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
            exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
            exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
        })
        .build();
HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
        .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
        .build();
Api client = httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(Api.class);
client.upload(info, file);
```

and

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(request -> {
        log.debug("--- Request -------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        request.headers().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.debug("{} -> {}", name, value)));
        log.debug("[ {} / {} ]", request.method(), request.url());
        log.debug("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        return Mono.just(request);
    });
}

private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
        HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = response.statusCode();
        log.debug("--- Response ------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        response.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.debug("{} -> {}", name, value)));
        log.debug("[ {} ]", httpStatusCode);
        ClientResponse clientResponse = response.mutate().body(dataBufferFlux -> dataBufferFlux.map(dataBuffer -> {
            log.debug("{}", dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            log.debug("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            return dataBuffer;
        })).build();
        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        });
}
```

For the response it is ok.

But I don't know how to "extract" the body parts of the request.

++EDIT++

I try can using

```
BodyInserter<?, ? super ClientHttpRequest> body = request.body();
```

If I'm looking in the debug mode of Intellij, I can see my class and it's json representation.

[image]

But how to use the body variable in my code the get it's content ?